# Disabling mod_autoindex dies on autoindex.conf being replaced

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

I was hardening my webserver - CentOS 7.5.1804, httpd 2.4.6_80 - and followed the myriad of examples that suggested disabling mod_autoindex. (see Commenting out `LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so`)

httpd doesn't restart because `/etc/httpd/conf.d/autoindex.conf` has entries that httpd no longer understands. Fine, removed `autoindex.conf`.

Then I updated the server, and found that `autoindex.conf` had been replaced in the update, again preventing the httpd from starting.

Does anyone know why `autoindex.conf` is

1. independant of `httpd.conf`
2. not wrapped in `<IfModule mod_autoindex></IfModule>` markers?

Subsequently, does anyone know how to turn `mod_autoindex` off and keep it off without threatening to prevent httpd from starting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why `autoindex.conf` is independant of `httpd.conf`

Well, it only contains directives related to mod_autoindex (the *Fancy* directory listing feature) so it makes sense to have these in a separate conf file. This conf file is *included* in the main server `httpd.conf` file. So, to disable mod_autoindex you should comment out the `LoadModule` line *and* comment out the corresponding `Include` directive.

If these directives weren't independent of `httpd.conf` then you would have considerably more editing to do in order to remove this module.

> why `autoindex.conf` is not wrapped in `<IfModule mod_autoindex></IfModule>` markers?

Well, it should be. And in later versions of Apache it does appear to be.

> how to turn `mod_autoindex` off and keep it off

I wouldn't *remove* the `autoindex.conf` file. I would just comment out the line that includes it in the main server config.

Comment: In CentOS 7 the module and conf loading looks like `Include conf.modules.d/*.conf` and `IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf` is there a way to make it load all except autoindex.conf ? (Or can we rename it without it coming back in a later update?)

Comment: @Smock The `Include` and `IncludeOptional` directives use `fnmatch()` style wildcards. It may be possible to exclude `autoindex.conf` using this method, but I imagine it could be prone to error (eg. exclude `a` from the first character, but are there any other conf files that start with `a` - in the future?). The cleanest approach would be to rename the file eg. `autoindex.conf-disabled`, so it doesn't match the wildcard, although I imagine another `autoindex.conf` may reappear in a future update.

Comment: Running into a similar issue. I'm going to try simply emptying the file or commenting everything in it. (yep, CentOS...)

Comment: @MSpreij Rather than removing/commenting everything in that file, you could wrap the entire contents of that file in a `<IfModule autoindex_module>` ... `</IfModule>` container.